# Should a bug listing have a delete button?

Tags: usability, interaction-design

I am working on a bug tracking system. Right now I am on the listing bugs page, where I have used a grid to list down a few details of the bug, like created date, reported by, priority etc...

I wanted to know if placing a delete button to delete the bug is good UX or not?

For this I have seen a few bug tracking tools, where I couldn't find the delete button in the listing page; once you click on the bug and go to the view bug page, there the delete button appears.

I need some advice on this.

Comment: Is this an internal bug tracking system or is an end user doing this?

Comment: internal bug tracking system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting bug reports makes for the ability to obliterate history. Closing bug reports is the way to "delete" them (take them off the to-do list) without obliterating history.

A reported bug may not be a bug at all, but you don't want to lose the fact that it was reported and why it was considered not to be a bug.

The fact that something was reported as a bug when it is not, may actually be very valuable information with regard to the design and usability of the software.